# PHP Weather website

Tags: javascript, php

This is a Weather project

http://mohammadhalawi.6te.net/Weather/index.php

when the user enters a correct city it return the weather and if he didn't enter anything there is an alert but when he enters a false one, this is when the problem happens, it's not returning an alert as it is supposed to do.

check out the link to test it.

so how do I make it return an alert that this city does not exist, also I'm using bootstrap

there is 3 divs with alert classes the id #success and #noCity are working but the #fail it's always empty.

so the point is I'm retrieving info from a weather website , and if this city exists the data will be in the div with id #success otherwise it if there is no such city the div with id #fail with show up , but it's not working.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTeyj.png)

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Weather App</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">



    <!--[if IE]>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center">
                <h1 class="text-center grey">Weather Prediction</h1>
                <p class="lead text-center grey">Enter your city below to get the forecast weather.</p>

                <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" id="city" placeholder="Eg. London, Paris, Beirut...">    
                </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" id="FindMyWeather" name="Weather">Find my weather</button>
                </form>
        <div class="alert alert-success" id="success"></div>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" id="fail">This city does not exist, please try again.</div>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" id="noCity">Please Enter a City.</div>

            </div>


        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="js/JQuery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**script.js**

```
$(function() {

    $('#FindMyWeather').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.alert').hide();
        if ($('#city').val() != "") {
            $.get("scraper.php?city=" + $('#city').val(), function(data) {


                if (data=="") {

                    $('#fail').fadeIn(500);

                } else {
                    $('#success').html(data).fadeIn(500);
                }

            });

        } else {
            $('#noCity').fadeIn(500);
        }

    });

});
```

**scraper.php**

```
<?php

$city=$_GET['city'];
$city=str_replace(" ","",$city);



$contents=file_get_contents("http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/".$city."/forecasts/latest");

preg_match('/3 Day Weather Forecast Summary:<\/b><span class="read-more-small"><span class="read-more-content"> <span class="phrase">(.*?)</s',$contents,$matches);


echo $matches[1];
?>
```

**style.css**

```
html
{
    height: 100%;
}
body
{
    background: url('../img/nature.jpg') center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.grey
{
    color: dimgrey;
}

p
{
    padding: 3% 0% 0%;
}
button
{
    margin-top: 5%;
}
.container
{
    padding-top: 15%;
}

.alert
{
    margin-top: 5%;
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.23em;
}
```

Comment: And what do you expect us to do? You have no question

Comment: there is a problem with the return of a false value just go to the website and put some random word it will return empty , while it should return city does not exist

Comment: if the city does exist it return the right weather but if not it returns empty check out the script.js and scraper.php files

Comment: Are you sure that you get an empty `data` if the location is false or maybe getting a `data` with an error in it?

Comment: if i'm on my computer using wamp i have an error but using a server from another website i have an empty result

Comment: i have a link above if you want to test the website

Answer (score 0):

When i debug your script i found

```
$(function() {   


    $('#FindMyWeather').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.alert').hide();
        if ($('#city').val() != "") {
            $.get("scraper.php?city=" + $('#city').val(), function(data) {


                if (data=="") {

                    $('#fail').fadeIn(500);

                } else {
                    $('#success').html(data).fadeIn(500);
                }

            });

        } else {
            $('#noCity').fadeIn(500);
        }

    });

});
```

your data response getting two enter spaces its not empty (it container two enters) that why its showing blank space check with debugger

try with

```
 $(function() {

    $('#FindMyWeather').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.alert').hide();
        if ($('#city').val() != "") {
            $.get("scraper.php?city=" + $('#city').val(), function(data) {
               data.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, "");
                if (data=="") {

                    $('#fail').fadeIn(500);

                } else {
                    $('#success').html(data).fadeIn(500);
                }

            });

        } else {
            $('#noCity').fadeIn(500);
        }

    });

});
```

Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: I did as u said and i edited my post check out the error image above , im using wamp on my computer for this website

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/fghjkl/forecasts/latest): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in

Comment: sorry but it didn't work, and i don't know if this helps but when the $matches[1] is empty if I echo "City does not exist" it works , there is an alert but it is using the div with id #success so i don't know if it is a php problem or javascript :(

Answer (score 0):

Change Your scraper.php

```
<?php
$city=$_GET['city'];
$city=str_replace(" ","",$city);

$site="http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/".$city."/forecasts/latest";

$old_error_reporting = error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_WARNING);
$content = file_get_contents($site);
error_reporting($old_error_reporting);
if ($content === FALSE) {
    $error = true;
} else {
    $tweets = $content;
    preg_match('/3 Day Weather Forecast Summary:<\/b><span class="read-more-small"><span class="read-more-content"> <span class="phrase">(.*?)</s',$tweets,$matches);
    $error = false;
}

if(!$error){
    echo $matches[0];
}else{
    echo "error";
}

?>
```

Script.js

```
if (data=="") {

                    $('#fail').fadeIn(500);

                }
                else if(data == "error"){
                    $('#fail').html('City Not Exist').fadeIn(500);
                }

                else {
                    $('#success').html(data).fadeIn(500);
                }
```

Hope it will work

Comment: What did you change? Why should it make a difference? Please express your answer in the form of an answer and not in the form of a game of spot-the-difference.